# tcsh script - Executing command with arguments and writing output to file

Tags: shell, scripting, tcsh

I have a program, readtree, which will read a tree structure and print the output to the shell. I want to redirect this shell output to a file. This program takes only 1 argument: the name of the file.

I have tried performing this with the following:

./readtree filename.tree 1>&! writtenOutput.txt

and even

`./readtree filename.tree` 1>&! writtenOutput.txt

But either way makes the shell think "1>&! writtenOutput.txt" are additional arguments, and my program produces an error complaining that more than a single argument is passed.

My question is how would I let the shell know to separate the output redirection command from the arguments of the program I want to run? Additionally, say I passed a variable to the program as an argument

eg. `./program firstArgument $secondArgument` 1>&! writtenOutput.txt

Would I need some extra syntax to account for the variable argument?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Where did you get that redirection syntax?  It looks like a mashup of sh (`1>`) with csh (`>&!`).  The extra argument being complained about is the `1`; lose it, and it should work as-is.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here: http://www.tcsh.org/tcsh.html/Input_output.html

There is a nice guide on available options for redirecting.

If you want to split stderr and stdout you can use:

```
(command > output-file) >& error-file
```